# Join result from two tables having same colomn avoiding duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with different data and I would like to join result in order to get data from both avoiding duplicates.

Table1:

```
Seasons  | Colors
win 17   | grey
win 17   | blue
win 18   | red
win 18   | black
```

Table2:

```
Seasons  | Sizes | Weights
win 17   | 48    |   8
win 17   | 47    |   7
win 17   | 48    |   5
win 17   | 47    |   9
win 18   | 42    |   2
win 18   | 43    |   3
win 18   | 42    |   4
win 18   | 43    |   1
```

Joining to something like :

```
Seasons  | Sizes | Weights | Colors
win 17   | 48    |   8    |  grey
win 17   | 47    |   7    |  grey
win 17   | 48    |   5    |  grey
win 17   | 47    |   9    |  grey
win 17   | 48    |   8    |  blue
win 17   | 47    |   7    |  blue
win 17   | 48    |   5    |  blue
win 17   | 47    |   9    |  blue
win 18   | 42    |   2    |  red
win 18   | 43    |   3    |  red
win 18   | 42    |   4    |  red
win 18   | 43    |   1    |  red
win 18   | 42    |   2    |  black
win 18   | 43    |   3    |  black
win 18   | 42    |   4    |  black
win 18   | 43    |   1    |  black
```

I have tried

```
SELECT
  Seasons,
  Sizes,
  Weights,
  Colors
FROM (SELECT
  Seasons,
  Colors
FROM Table1) c
CROSS JOIN (SELECT
  Sizes,
  Weights
FROM table2) s
WHERE c.Seasons = s.Seasons
GROUP BY Seasons,
         Colors,
         Sizes,
         Weights;
```

But I get duplicate colors on same season with different sizes and codes

Answer (score 1):

**TRY THIS:** You can try `JOIN` with `DISTINCT` but I don't understand why you are storing data in such a way you can normalize it in better way.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Seasons, 
    t2.Sizes,
    t2.Weights,
    t1.Colors
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.Seasons = t2.Seasons
```